# Nested ternary javascript

Tags: javascript, nested, ternary

Having some trouble with a nested ternary:

**Brief:**

Return: a string formatted as a list of names separated by commas except for the last two names, which should be separated by an ampersand.

**Example input and output:**

```
list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ])
// returns 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'

list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'} ])
// returns 'Bart & Lisa'

list([ {name: 'Bart'} ])
// returns 'Bart'
```

**My JS:**

```
var cache = '';
var data = [ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'}];
  for (i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
    var people = data[i];

        cache += people.name + 
        (i==((length === 2) || (length === -1 )) ? ' & ' : // (if has two or is before last)
        (i==((length >= 3 ) || (length < 2)) ? ', ' : '') //not:(if has two or is before last) + >= 3 or < 2
        );
  }
```

THREE IS WORKING but not one or two

Comment: You don't have the `length` defined at all?

Comment: Why do you iterate over all elements if you want to treat the last one different?  You could do something like `data.slice(0, -1).map(d => d.name).join(', ') + (d.length > 1 ? (' & ' + data[data.length - 1].name) : '')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
function list(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(person) { return person.name; }) // Use only .name
  .join(", ") // Join with ", "
  .replace(/, (?!.*, )/, " & "); // Replace last ", " with " & "
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried something like this:

```js
function list(data) {
  var arr = [];
  data.map(function (v, i) {
    arr.push(v.name);
  });
  var last = arr.pop();
  return (arr.length > 0) ? arr.join(", ") + " & " + last : last;
}


console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ]));
// returns 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'

console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'} ]));
// returns 'Bart & Lisa'

console.log(list([ {name: 'Bart'} ]));
// returns 'Bart'
```

Comment: Either use `forEach` or assign the return value of `data.map` to `arr`, but not both ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Sure, when did I used "both"?

Comment: Well, you are using `map` and manually push values to an array.

Comment: @FelixKling What the crap of me! `:(` So is it that it could be like: `arr = data.map(function (v, i) {
    return v.name;
  });` Right?

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is just off for the length checks.

```
var cache = '';
var data = [ {name: 'Homer'}, {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'}];

for (i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
var people = data[i];

    cache += people.name + 
    (i < (data.length - 2) ? ', ' : 
        (i === (data.length - 2) ? ' & ' : ''));
}
```

result: `"Homer, Bart, Lisa & Maggie"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler way to accomplish what you want

```
function list(data) {
  var firstNames = data.slice(0, -1).map(x => x.name).join(', ');
  var lastName = data.slice(-1).map(x => x.name);
  return [firstNames, lastName].filter(Boolean).join(' & ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function only makes one trip through your array without any magic, and should produce quite consistent results.

```
function getString(data){
    var concat =  data.reduce(function(curr, next, i){
        var separator = (i === data.length - 1) ? ' & ' : ', ';
        return {name: curr.name + separator + next.name};
    });
    return concat.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way

```
var list = (names) =>  names.map(person => person.name).join(', ').replace(/(.*),(.*)$/, "$1 &$2")
```

Note that the arrow function is in accordance with ES6.